# Why cannot load listItem using Word API Javascript?

Tags: office-js, office365api, word-addins, office365connectors

I have the next function:

```
 export async function checkingParagraphs () {
  await window.Word.run(async context => {
    const paragraphs = context.document.body.paragraphs
    context.load(paragraphs, 'text,tableNestingLevel,isListItem,listItem')
    await context.sync()

    for (let i = 0; i < paragraphs.items.length; i++) {
       console.log('Paragraph:', paragraphs.items[i].text)
       console.log('This paragraph is in a table? ', (paragraphs.items[i].tableNestingLevel === 1))
       console.log('This paragraph is in a list item? ',paragraphs.items[i].isListItem)
       console.log('This paragraph is in a list item? ',paragraphs.items[i].listItem)
   }
  })
}
```

If I removed the 'listItem' option inside of load method is running but if I add it then the function not runs.

Thank you for your time!
BR!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is expected. If any of the paragraphs in `context.document.body.paragraphs` is NOT a list item, then `listItem` will throw an error when it reaches that paragraph in the loop. See [Paragraph.listItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.paragraph?view=word-js-preview#listitem).